# return a html file in rest service with all css and js files

Tags: html, web-services, rest

I have to create a rest service to return a HTML file along with the CSS and JS . I will be getting the name of the html file as part of the request.

I tried providing the path of the html file as a property and reading the file content and sending as text/html. But this will not send the file with css and js.

1. Where do I keep all these files(ideally)? Should it be in web app or something ?
2. How to return the css and js with the html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host your JS and CSS files in separate website and give the links to CSS and JS in your HTML.. this way you will get a performance bonus also as your JS and CSS are cachable.

It should work fine..

If you have very less CSS and JS then you can append it to html and send to client

Answer (score 2):

I want to give another answer here. Of course you can provide the static files completly via your REST service and store the files on the server where your REST service is running.

If the first request calls the path **/example/index** and the response contains your html-file, the browser of the client will load all referenced static files by sending a GET request back to the server. Assuming that you referenced the files **css/style.css** and **js/script.js** in your html-file, there will be two more GET requests **/example/css/style.css** and **/example/js/script.js**. Your REST service must provide the files under this path now and your clients will have all static files.

Answer (score -1):

you make a mistake when you try to load a full view with REST. 
REST is usefull to load data. Not displaying.

If you want load the full html content, you should use iframe or load your data with REST and make your own page.

Comment: If I have to use iFrame, can I send the html file as a link in my json and from the mobile device load that link ?